# From Matrix form to Observation form

Tags: matrices

How to get the number of observations "n" from matrix form in question below? Can you show me step by step The answer is n=2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

$n$ need not be $2$.

There is not enough information to reconstruct $n$.

Suppose $Z_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ and $y_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 1}$.

We can let $Z_2 = \begin{bmatrix} Z_1 \\ 0^T\end{bmatrix}$ and $y_2=\begin{bmatrix}y_1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$.

Then $Z_2^TZ_2=\begin{bmatrix} Z_1^T  & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} Z_1 \\ 0^T\end{bmatrix}=Z_1^TZ_1$

and $Z_2^Ty_2=\begin{bmatrix} Z_1^T  & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}y_1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}=Z_1^Ty_1$.

That is I have manage to construct another matrix of different $n$ that would give you the same values of $Z^TZ$ and $Z^Ty$, hence the information provided can't uniquely specify $n$.

However, the smallest $n$ will  have to be $2$ since $Z^TZ$ is a rank-$2$ matrix.